# Is it possible to undo the purchase action of an iOS app?

Tags: applications, ios-appstore

I have downloaded a lot of apps on App Store.

I want to undo the purchase action of some apps so that I won't have to re-download them when I get a new device. It's pretty annoying to see a new device filled with ancient apps which haven't been maintained for years.

What should I do?

Comment: When you set up your device are you inheriting a backup of some sort?

Comment: you can hide purchases in the app store by going into your account to "My Purchases" and swiping left on any app you don't want anymore...

Comment: @bmike I don't know. I just entered my apple credentials and the apps are coming up. And some devices are not even new ones but those I found from old shelves in my office.

Comment: @SteveChambers May I ask where can I find the "My Purchases"?

Comment: on the first screen of the Account page, tap Purchased.